# Filter SQL Server Records by Latest Date on Every Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, subquery, not-exists

How would I filter this SQL server database so only the green records are left aka the last recorded date every year for each `Customer ID` field.

[image: SQL database]

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please add your table structure

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the rows, not only the date values, using `ROW_NUMBER()` is an option (you only need to use the appropriate `PARTITON BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT 
      CustomerId, 
      [Date], 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId, YEAR[Date] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS Rn
   FROM YourTable 
) t
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the maximum date in the year, you can write a query to get for each year the date where not exists another (in the same year), as follow:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
    FROM yourtable t2
    WHERE t1.customerID = t2.customerID
    AND t1.date > t2.date
    AND DATEPART(YEAR, t1) = DATEPART(YEAR, t2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two columns, then you can just use aggregation:

```
select customer_id, max(date)
from t
group by customer_id, year(date);
```